# How to prove or disprove that $f(p):=\min\{{\rm sec}(X,Y)\,\,|\,\, X,X\neq Y\in T_pM\},$ is smooth function?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $(M,g)$ be a compact Riemannian manifold and let ${\rm sec}(X,Y)$ denote sectional curvature of plane spanned by $X,Y\in T_pM$. Then

> How to prove or disprove that $f(p)$ defined by
>   $$f(p):=\min\{{\rm sec}(X,Y)\,\,|\,\, X,X\neq Y\in T_pM\},$$
>   is a smooth function on $M$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not, in general. For example, you could let $M = \mathbb R^2 \times N$ with a product metric, where $\mathbb R^2$ has the Euclidean metric and $N$ is a surface of revolution whose Gaussian curvature transitions smoothly from positive to negative, such as the surface illustrated below. With a little care, you could make the Gaussian curvature of the surface equal to something like $-z$, and then the minimum sectional curvature of the product manifold would be $\min(-z,0)$, which is not smooth.
[image]

Comment: Once again intuitively answer by prof. Lee. Thank you I really appreciate your help. and I think it is easy to convert your example to compact case. isn't it?

Comment: Right. Just close up the surface smoothly on the top & bottom, and take a product with a flat torus instead of $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: ..Because I am big spender, I give you +1000 point for your answer :) I hope you use these points wisely!

Comment: Thank you!!!!!!

Comment: Too late... Is $f$ always continuous? (... and in second line I think you mean $N$ by $M$?)

Comment: @C.F.G: Thanks for the correction -- fixed now.

Comment: @C.F.G: Yes, it's always continuous. One way to see this is that if you choose a local orthonormal frame over an open set $U\subseteq M$, then you can view $f$ locally as a function from $U\times G(2,n)$ to $\mathbb R$, where $G(2,n)$ is the Grassmannian of $2$-planes in $\mathbb R^n$. Since $G(2,n)$ is compact, it's pretty easy to prove using sequences that $f$ is continuous.

Comment: @C.F.G: StackExchange frowns on asking an entirely new question in comments. But since you asked, you're right: the first is already in my [correction list](https://sites.math.washington.edu/~lee/Books/RM/), and I just added the second.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108157/discussion-between-jack-lee-and-c-f-g).